# How to fork a background process in Jenkins? Setting BUILD_ID and using nohup seems to be non working

Tags: maven, ant, groovy, jenkins

I have a maven job in Jenkins(version 1.578). The maven snippet (Ant script written in Groovy code) below starts a Fuse server, and I cannot make Jenkins to leave it running after the job finishes.

```
<profile>
    <id>start-fuse</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-fuse</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>
                            <![CDATA[
                                def fuseBinDirectory = '${fuse.dir}/bin'
                                ant.exec(executable:'bash', dir:fuseBinDirectory, failonerror:true, osfamily:'unix') {
                                    ant.env(key:'BUILD_ID',value:'DO_NOT_STOP_MY_PROCESS_JENKINS')
                                    ant.env(key:'KARAF_OPTS',value:'${KARAF_OPTS}')
                                    ant.arg(value:"-c")
                                    ant.arg(value:"nohup ./start ${fuse.start.parameters} </dev/null >> nohup.out 2>&1&")
                                }
                            ]]>
                            </source>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

What do I wrong?

How can I fork a similar Fuse process under Windows so that Jenkins does not kill it?

### UPDATE - SOLUTION

Adding the 4 env entries mentioned in the accepted answer works both on windows and linux. So no matter which job type you have you can have something like this:

```
ant.exec(executable:'sh', dir:fuseBinDirectory, failonerror:true, osfamily:'unix') {
    ant.env(key:'BUILD_ID',value:'DO_NOT_STOP_MY_PROCESS_JENKINS')
    ant.env(key:'HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE',value:'DO_NOT_STOP_MY_PROCESS_JENKINS')
    ant.env(key:'JENKINS_COOKIE',value:'DO_NOT_STOP_MY_PROCESS_JENKINS')
    ant.env(key:'JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE',value:'DO_NOT_STOP_MY_PROCESS_JENKINS')
    ant.env(key:'HUDSON_COOKIE',value:'DO_NOT_STOP_MY_PROCESS_JENKINS')
    ant.env(key:'KARAF_OPTS',value:'${KARAF_OPTS}')
    ant.arg(line:'-c "./start ${fuse.start.parameters}"')
}
```

Nohup seems to be non neccessary at all.

Comment: Is this job created using free-style template?

Comment: No. Normal maven 2/3 job.

Comment: Can you change the same to freestyle job and give a try? Many have faced the same issue when using non-freestyle job. BUILD_ID worked for them when they switched to freestyle job.

Comment: Interesting. With freestyle job it does work. So my fuse remains running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will notice the comment by user 'mdp' in [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2729) page, you will notice that in case of jobs created using freestyle template, BUILD_ID does work. There are many others who faced similar issue. Such issues were seen only when it was a non-freestyle job.

Alternatively, should also check unsetting the following variables: HUDSON_COOKIE, HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE, JENKINS_COOKIE or JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE as suggested by few (Comments section) in [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build) link.

Comment: Adding all the 4 env entries to the forked process works also with Maven project. Thanks for referring to the solution. I add the modified solution.

Comment: Great! Glad to see that it worked after unsetting the variables in Maven project although which of these four is actually responsible still remains a mystery. :)

Comment: I don't really care. It does not disturb me to have 4.