# How to set environment entries for a Karaf instance started by Karaf admin service?

Tags: java, jenkins, environment-variables, karaf, pax-exam

I am testing a clustering solution for Felix with Pax Exam and Karaf (see http://planet.jboss.org/post/advanced_integration_testing_with_pax_exam_karaf). I start up several Karaf instances and play with them in the test.

If I want to be sure that the Karaf instances will be stopped in Jenkins when my test is aborted for some reason then I need to set some environment entries for the forked containers (see [How to fork a background process in Jenkins? Setting BUILD_ID and using nohup seems to be non working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25639678/337621)) Is there a way to do so? I can set system properties with the [admin:create command option called --java-opts](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/commands/admin-create.html) but I cannot set any environment entry for the forked process. Do you know any way or trick to set them?